# Where can I find a description of file system mount options in Linux?

Tags: linux, filesystems

Is there some file in Linux that enumerates and describes mount options for file systems like /etc/services describes ports?

Comment: Are you just looking for generic info or is this an indirect version of "How do I mount a filesystem of type [fill_in_the_blank] under Linux?  If generic info I'd suggest a wiki search first, followed by a more specific question here - if you still have one.

Comment: Generic info, so I found it in mount(8)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you're asking for "Which filesystems are mounted, and how are they mounted?", the answer can be found by either reading /proc/mounts or running 'mount'.

If you're asking which mount options you have available for the different file systems, you need to check the man page for mount (mount(8)) - it has one section titled "FILESYSTEM SPECIFIC MOUNT OPTIONS", and one titled "FILESYSTEM INDEPENDENT MOUNT OPTIONS" which should give you a pretty good idea of what mount options are available and what they do.

Comment: Thank you very much. I was should to search it in man mount by my self...

Answer (score 0):

There is no machine-parsable file like `/etc/services`, as far as I know.

The most accessible human-readable documentation is the man page for the `mount` command.

Sometimes though the `mount` command is not completely up-to-date, there can be options that the kernel supports but not `mount`. The options supported by the kernel are documented in its documentation under `Documentation/filesystems/`. Options not supported by the `mount` command are typically experimental and best left alone in any case; but they sometimes appear in `/proc/mounts` when they are the names of options that are enabled by default and best not turned *off*.